# addClass only if cookie exists else hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

I'm trying to make a voting system that will check when user has voted and then change the html item css from "Vote" to "Thank you" and the background color to "green".

Now this works great, but I need to make the option when user refreshes the page to check if cookie exists (the cookie is already set = variable is voteCookie('id')) and then apply the class="exists". If it doesn't exist hide that class. That class would say "Thanks for voting", nothing else.

jQuery:

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    var voteId = $('.gallery-item a');
    $(voteId).on('click', function() {
        $(this).text('Thank you!');
        $(this).css('background-color', 'green');       
});
});
```

Comment: Where is the cookie code? I can't see voteCookie('id') in your code

Comment: It is already set by that cookie id, so no point to paste the code here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *can* do that (it's made easier with the jQuery cookie plugin), but it's not the correct use case for cookies. Cookies get sent from the client to the server with every HTTP request; if you're not using that information on every HTTP request, that's just completely unnecessary data transfer.

Consider local storage instead, which is supported by [virtually all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage), even IE8:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var voteLink = $('.gallery-item a');
    if (localStorage.getItem("voted")) {
        voteLink.text('Thank you for voting').addClass('voted');
    } else {
        voteLink.one('click', function() {
            localStorage.setItem("voted", "yes");
            $(this).text('Thank you!');
            voteLink.addClass('voted');
            // If you wanted to do something with *just* the elements that weren't
            // clicked, you could do:
            // voteLink.not(this).addClass('unused-vote');
            // ...or similar
        });
    }
});
```

...but if you want to use cookies, with the jQuery cookie plugin, you just change the `getItem` line to `if ($.cookie('voted'))` and the `setItem` line to `$.cookie('voted', 'yes');`

I made a few other changes above as well:

- I used `document` rather than `window` with `ready` - [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) only talks about `document`, not `window`. (That said, I generally prefer not to use `ready` at all; instead, I just ensure scripts are at the end of the HTML, just before the closing `</body>` tag.)
- I called the variable `voteLink` rather than `voteId` since it's a jQuery object containing an `a` element, not an ID.
- I changed `$(voteId)` to `voteLink` because the object is **already** a jQuery object, no need to pass it through `$()` again.
- I changed the direct style manipulation to a class you add, for better separation of logic and styling.
- I added that same class when they've already voted.
- I used `one` rather than `on` so that we remove the click handler on the first click.

---

Obviously, this just has the client code. I assume there's a server piece that validates votes and such (since you can't trust anything the client sends or stores for you).

Comment: Amazing, I'll let you know how this work for me. Thanks.

Comment: Now, what happens is because '.gallery-item a' is same for all, each voting options changes. That is why I've been using $(this).

Comment: @stormec: Doh, sorry, yeah. But you don't need `$(voteId)`, just the `this` within the `click`. I've fixed it.

Comment: Oh my bad, I haven't stated before. Each user should be allowed to vote three times only. How do I make this now?

Comment: @stormec: You make that *server-side*. You can't trust anything from the client. How you do that is well outside the scope of the question you originally asked.

Comment: So there is no way I can do it with jQuery?

Comment: @stormec: It's nothing to do with jQuery. How could you do this on the client at all? When the user can erase cookies/storage any time they want? Or spoof HTTP requests to your server?

Comment: Well this is only for internal use of the company, so targeted are the people who know nothing about cookies or localStorage. :)

Comment: Therefor, jQuery solution would be just fine mate.

Comment: @stormec: You can store the number of times they've voted in local storage as well. Note that you can only store strings, so you'll want to parse when you retrieve the value. If it's anything more than just a simple number, I find using JSON is very handy: `var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"));` which will give you `null` if it wasn't there, then `localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data));` for storing your data later.

Comment: Wow.. sorry but I never used JSON. Is there a chance you can edit the upper code so it stores 3 votes only?
Thanks, I have already marked this as the best answer. :)